# ibus issue in 23.10: AltGr as deadkey no longer functional

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I customized a keyboard layout for Sanskrit transliteration (sa-iast.mim) to use with ibus. It uses various deadkeys, including accents as well as also AltGr.

The syntax looks like this:

(map
(trans
((G-a) "ā")
((G-A) "Ā")
("^a"  "â")
("^A"  "Â")
))

(state
(init
(trans)))

Now, the accents work as deadkeys as expected, but AltGr doesn't. It used to work perfectly in 22.10 and 23.04, however.

It doesn't work means, to be precise, that the key combination supposed to produce "ā", for instance, produces the character "æ".

Any ideas what might have changed this behaviour?